# Pascal: Project raising External: SIGSEGV when interacting with Form

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, segmentation-fault

Let's say, there are 3 forms in a project (Form1, Form2, Form3). Form1 has a button on it with the OnClick event set to `Form2.Show`. This code executes perfectly, however if Form2's code tries to call `Form3.Show`, then the project raises an EXTERNAL: SIGSEGV pointing to Customform.inc

> Project project1 raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'
>
> In file '.\include\customform.inc' at line 2196:
>
> Visible := True;

This is exactly what's happening to my project. All forms were properly created and declared, and the units are linked perfectly. The compilation goes fine, without any errors or warnings.

So it is impossible to make the third form visible. But I've discovered that every kind of interaction would result in an External: SIGSEGV error pointing to random pieces of code which compile and run just fine. I just can't figure out the origin of the error.

If I try to execute my project without the debugger, I get an Access Violation error. Failing code:

```
procedure TWarForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Begin
   Form3.Show;
end;
```

from

```
unit work;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, ExtCtrls,
  StdCtrls, BGRAFlashProgressBar, AuthUnit;

type

  { TWarForm }

  TWarForm = class(TForm)
    ArcaneDustIMG: TImage;
    ProgressBar: TBGRAFlashProgressBar;
    ArcaneEDT: TEdit;
    GoldEDT: TEdit;
    GoldIMG: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Wallpaper: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WallpaperMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure WallpaperMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure WallpaperMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  WarForm: TWarForm;
  MouseIsDown: Boolean;
  PX, PY: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TWarForm }

procedure TWarForm.WallpaperMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then begin
    MouseIsDown := True;
    PX := X;
    PY := Y;
  end;
end;

procedure TWarForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Begin
   Form3.Show;
end;

procedure TWarForm.WallpaperMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if MouseIsDown then begin
    SetBounds(WarForm.Left + (X - PX), WarForm.Top + (Y - PY), WarForm.Width, WarForm.Height);
  end;
end;

procedure TWarForm.WallpaperMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  MouseIsDown:=False;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Form3` has been initialized before creation of `TWarForm`? Your description says you get an error when you try to do a form show on the click of a button, but your code is attempting to show a form during the creation of another form (the main form?).

Comment: Delphi doesn't raise SIGSEGV, so this isn't Delphi related, and Pascal doesn't have forms or event handlers. I've removed the inappropriate tags. Don't use random tags that don't apply to your question just to get attention; use tags that actually are applicable to your post. Also, your code is incomplete. You don't have a unit in your uses clause for Form3 that I can see. Where do you create `Form3`? If you set a breakdown on the `Form3.Show` line, what does the debugger tell you when you evaluate `Form3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the forms either manualy or set them to "auto create" in your IDE

To Create them manualy just change your code slightly:

```
 TWarForm = class(TForm)
    ArcaneDustIMG: TImage;
    ProgressBar: TBGRAFlashProgressBar;
    ArcaneEDT: TEdit;
    GoldEDT: TEdit;
    GoldIMG: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Wallpaper: TImage;

    Form2: TForm2; // insert Form2
    Form3: TForm3; // and Form3

    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WallpaperMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure WallpaperMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure WallpaperMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

  ..

  procedure TWarForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  Begin
    Form3 := TForm3.Create(Self);
    Form3.Show;
  end;
```

**If you do so, don't forget to call Form3.Free at the end of your application execution.**